# How to iterate in a certain order?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I'm wondering how I can iterate through a list in a certain order in Python.

Given the list, `lst = [1, 3, -1, 2]`, I want my function to iterate such that the next number iterated over will be the index of the value of the current number.

lst[0] -> lst[1] -> lst[3] -> lst[2]
1 -> 3 -> 2 -> -1

Comment: This is one of those question that practically ask for it: **why** would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple variables that you have not specified:

1. What kind of error handling should this include?
2. Do you want it to loop indefinitely?

Assuming that the respective answers are "None" and "Yes", here's one way of doing it:

```
def create_iter(arr):
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield arr[i]
        i = arr[i]

lst = [1,3,-1,2]
my_iterator = create_iter(lst)
```

This gives:

```
>>> for _ in range(10):
>>>    print (next(my_iterator))
1
3
2
-1
2
-1
2
-1
2
-1
```

Comment: Good, but why not simply `for i in create_iter(lst): print(i)`?

Comment: @zvone Because that causes an infinite loop

Comment: Ah that :) Well, it should ;)

Comment: Note that if a value is at the index of that value, then it will just keep repeating the same value

Comment: @sabbahillel That's right. The OP doesn't specify what behavior he wants in that case, but it's easy enough to add `if i == arr[i]: break` and/or a `try` block to catch an `IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you check that each value is within the list except that you must have an end of list condition, then you would have

```
index = 0
while True:
    newindex = mylist[index]
    if newindex >= len(mylist):
        break
    elif newindex == index:
         break
     else:
         index = newindex
```

Note that if every entry in the list is a valid index, then you would get an infinite loop.